# Configure c3p0 to throw an error in case of invalid useranme/password

Tags: c3p0

I wonder if there is an easy way to prevent c3p0 connection pool from acquiring connection if provided login information is incorrect? I want it to throw an exception in this case and ignore `acquireRetryAttempts` parameter.
The reason I'm asking is because RDMS may be configured to block account after a few unsuccessful attempts, and I want to minimize the chances it happens.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set acquireRetryAttempts to 1, c3p0 will throw an Exception immediately if a Connection acquisition fails, and will not retry until a new client tries to Connect. if you want it not to try again even when new clients come, set the config parameter breakAfterAcquireFailure to true.

see
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#acquireRetryAttempts
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#breakAfterAcquireFailure

(it would be clearer if acquireRetryAttempts had been named "numAcquireAttempts". sigh.)

good luck!